# Delete singular entries

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-delete, mysql-error-1111

If I have this table:

```
+------+-------+---------------+--------+-----------------+------------+-----------+----------------+------+------+--------+------------+------------+
| type | class | username      | userid | userip          | usermobile | useremail | daysleft| pin1 | pin2 | pin3 | active | schoolname | schoolsite |
+------+-------+---------------+--------+-----------------+------------+-----------+----------------+------+------+--------+------------+------------+
| B    | A     | sebbetest     |   1000 | 123.123.123.123 | none       | none      |       50| 0    | 0    | 0    | Y      | none       | none       | 
| A    | A     | stackowerflow |   5355 | 123.123.123.123 | none       | none      |       50| 0    | 0    | 0    | Y      | none       | haha       | 
| C    | A     | good          |   4223 | 123.123.123.124 | none       | none      |       50| 0    | 0    | 0    | Y      | none       | haha       | 
| A    | A     | tester        |   6353 | 123.123.123.125 | none       | none      |       50| 0    | 0    | 0    | Y      | none       | haha       | 
| B    | A     | admin         |   3453 | 123.123.123.125 | none       | none      |       50| 0    | 0    | 0    | Y      | none       | eeee       | 
| A    | A     | sebastian     |   1342 | 123.123.123.126 | none       | none      |       50| 0    | 0    | 0    | Y      | none       | eeee       | 
| C    | A     | username      |   6456 | 123.123.123.125 | none       | none      |       50| 0    | 0    | 0    | Y      | none       | woooooow   | 
+------+-------+---------------+--------+-----------------+------------+-----------+----------------+------+------+--------+------------+------------+
```

As you see, the user "good" with the IP "123.123.123.124" AND user "sebastian" with IP "123.123.123.126" has no "companions", no other users on the same IP.

The user "sebbetest" has a companion "stackowerflow".

The user "tester" has 2 companions: "admin" and "username".

Now I want to delete these users that lack companions. How I do? For atomic reasons and to prevent concurrent access from munging the database, I would want to delete all "non-companion" users in a single expression of SQL.

I tried with:
DELETE FROM lan WHERE COUNT(userip) = 1;

got this:
ERROR 1111 (HY000): Invalid use of group function

No rows are duplicates.
If there is a need to check if a entry is unique regardless of IP, (type, userid) is unique.

In other words, if IP is unique in a row, delete it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
DELETE FROM lan
 WHERE userip IN (SELECT x.userip
                   FROM (SELECT yt.userip
                           FROM lan yt
                       GROUP BY yt.userip
                         HAVING COUNT(*) = 1) x )
```

You get the error because you can't use COUNT, or any other aggregate functions in the `WHERE` clause while outside of a subquery.  Only in the `HAVING` clause can you reference aggregate functions in that manner.

It's possible this might work:

```
  DELETE FROM lan 
GROUP BY userip
  HAVING COUNT(*) = 1;
```

### Warning

With every DELETE statement, check and double check that the statement will select what you want for deletion.  If you are using InnoDB tables, wrap the DELETE in a transaction so you can use `ROLLBACK` if necessary.

Comment: mysql> DELETE FROM lan WHERE userip IN (SELECT yt.userip FROM lan yt GROUP BY yt.userip HAVING COUNT(*) = 1);
ERROR 1093 (HY000): You can't specify target table 'lan' for update in FROM clause

Comment: @sebastian nielsen: Fixed, sorry - forgot about MySQL's erroneous 1093 error.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it this way:

```
DELETE l1
FROM lan l1 LEFT OUTER JOIN lan l2 
  ON l1.userip = l2.userip AND l1.username <> l2.username
WHERE l2.userid IS NULL
```

In other words, try to match `l1` to its companion `l2` using an outer join.  If no match is found, then `l2` will be all nulls.  Where that happens, delete `l1`.

Comment: +1: I default to most widely supported syntax, not used to JOIN support in the UPDATE & DELETE...

Comment: Yeah if the OP hadn't tagged this `mysql` I wouldn't suggest it.  But it's such a natural and useful feature that I'm surprised it *isn't* part of standard SQL.